# How to get a Date-range in Angular9 usind Date() and DatePipe() Only?

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript

I needed a list of dates starting from a certain date ( this one depends on the data length...) so as to use the list as a lineChartLabel...

```
    getAllDays(){
    var l =[]
    var currentDate  = new Date()
    var pastDate  = new Date()
    var pipe = new DatePipe('en-US')
    this.corona.getTotalDaysdata().subscribe((data)=>{
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        pastDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() -i)
        var from = pipe.transform(pastDate, 'dd-MMM')
        l.push(from)
      }
    })
    console.log(l)
  return l
  }
```

But the result is this :
You can see that Element 18 is Wrong

```
0: "17-Dec" 
1: "16-Dec" 
2: "15-Dec" 
3: "14-Dec" 
4: "13-Dec" 
5: "12-Dec" 
6: "11-Dec" 
7  : "10-Dec" 
8: "09-Dec" 
9: "08-Dec" 
10: "07-Dec" 
11: "06-Dec" 
12: "05-Dec" 
13: "04-Dec" 
14:  "03-Dec" 
15: "02-Dec" 
16: "01-Dec" 
17: "30-Nov" 
18: "30-0ct" 
19: "28-Sep" 
20: "28-Aug" 
21: "  27-juil "
```

Comment: In Stackoverflow, it is strongly recommended that the code or error messages in question are not attached as images. Can you revise your question according to community guidelines?

See below for more information.

Comment: [DO NOT post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)\
[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Fixed, sorry...

Comment: What's wrong and how you want your results to be printed. could you provide a more detailed description of what you did to solve this?

Comment: In addition, the image link is completely deleted, but in the case of code and logs, can you wrap the codeblock to make it look more intuitive? Currently, the code and logs are broken.

Comment: I needed a list of dates starting from a certain date ( this one depends on the data length...) so as to use the list as a lineChartLabel... the problem is dates are wrong, if youcan see the element (17 and 18) you ll understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified the code a bit to help you understand. Let's first look at the incorrectly implemented code below.

```js
var l =[];
var currentDate = new Date('2020-12-10');

for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - i);
    console.log(currentDate.getDate());
    let date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(currentDate);
    
    l.push(date);
}

console.log(l);
```

```
# bad results
[
    '12/10/2020', '12/9/2020',
    '12/7/2020',  '12/4/2020',
    '11/30/2020', '11/25/2020',
    '11/19/2020', '11/12/2020',
    '11/4/2020',  '10/26/2020',
    '10/16/2020', '10/5/2020'
]
```

lets see loop, `currentDate.getDate()` value

```
[i]
[0]  10 - 0 = 10 (Dec) - 12/10/2020
[1]  10 - 1 =  9 (Dec) - 12/9/2020
[2]   9 - 2 =  7 (Dec) - 12/7/2020
[3]   7 - 3 =  4 (Dec) - 12/4/2020
[4]   4 - 4 =  0 (???) - 12/0/2020 -> 11/30/2020 (30-0)
[5]  30 - 5 = 25 (Nov) - 11/25/2020
[6]  25 - 6 = 19 (Nov) - 11/19/2020
[7]  19 - 7 = 12 (Nov) - 11/12/2020
[8]  12 - 8 =  4 (Nov) - 11/04/2020
[9]   4 - 9 = -5 (???) - 11/-5/2020 -> 10/26/2020 (31-5)
[10] 26 - 10= 16 (Oct) - 10/16/2020
[11] 16 - 11=  5 (Oct) - 10/5/2020
```

If initialization is not performed within the loop, the value calculated in the previous loop is maintained as it is.

---

#### Solve it by doing an initialization in the loop.

```js
var l =[];

for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    let currentDate = new Date('2020-12-10');
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - i);
    console.log(currentDate.getDate());

    let date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(currentDate);
    l.push(date);
}

console.log(l);
```

```
# good results
[
  '12/10/2020', '12/9/2020',
  '12/8/2020',  '12/7/2020',
  '12/6/2020',  '12/5/2020',
  '12/4/2020',  '12/3/2020',
  '12/2/2020',  '12/1/2020',
  '11/30/2020', '11/29/2020'
]
```

```
[0] 10 - 0 = 10 - 12/10/2020
[1] 10 - 1 =  9 - 12/9/2020
...
...
[10] 10 - 10 =  0 - 12/0/2020  -> 11/30/2020
[11] 10 - 11 = -1 - 12/-1/2020 -> 11/29/2020
```

Comment: Seems really clear to me, thank you! Is there any way to get the results for each iteration in the loop ( same as your second part in your response ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Declaring dates inside the loop resolved the problem, but still I didn't understand why I should declare it it this way...

```
      getAllDays(){
    var l =[]
    this.corona.getTotalDaysdata().subscribe((data)=>{
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var currentDate  = new Date()
        var pastDate  = new Date()
        var pipe = new DatePipe('en-US')    
        pastDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - i)
        var from = pipe.transform(pastDate, 'dd-MMM')
        l.push(from)
      }
    })
    console.log(l)
  return l
  }
```